# Using .net core to download a file from internet

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to download a file from internet to local folder with .net core, although it compiles without warnings or errors when executed it shows an error

```
using System;

namespace download_file
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string zip_url = @"https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.5/python-3.9.5-embed-amd64.zip";
            string current_directory = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string dl_path = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(System.String.Format(@"{0}\DL", current_directory)).FullName;
            
            string[] zip_url_words = zip_url.Split('/', 1);
            string downloaded_file_path = System.String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", dl_path, zip_url_words[zip_url_words.Length - 1]);

            // downloading the embedded python zip file
            file_download(zip_url, downloaded_file_path);

            void file_download(string url, string save_path)
            {
                if (url is null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                string[] url_word_array = url.Split('/', 1);

                if (save_path is null)
                {
                    save_path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\" + url_word_array[url_word_array.Length - 1];  //rsplit
                }
                System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
                client.DownloadFile(url, save_path);
                //System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key...")
                //System.Console.ReadLine()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your `save_path` contains a `:`, which is not valid in Windows file paths

Comment: Your file is trying to be saved within a `bin\Debug` subfolder... Surely you don't want this?

Comment: Also, use `Path.Join` (or `Path.Combine` on older .NET versions) to construct paths, rather than `string.Format`

Comment: ... But the problem is ultimately that `zip_url.Split('/', 1);` where the `1` tells `Split` to produce at most 1 substring... Meaning that it won't do anything at all! So `zip_url_words` contains a single element, which is the whole of `zip_url`, including that pesky `:` character. I recommend learning how to use a debugger, so you can easily find these sorts of problems yourself

Comment: yes, @canton7, I just identified that my problem actually comes from that line `string[] url_word_array = url.Split('/', 1);`, Split seems to not work as I would expect.

Comment: Do not use the WebClient class, it's obsolete. Use HttpClient instead.

Comment: @zooid the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_) are pretty clear: the '1' is the maximum number of elements in the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
string[] zip_url_words = zip_url.Split('/', 1);
```

From the documentation:

> ```
>     public String[] Split(char[]? separator, int count);
> ```

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Splits a string into a maximum number substrings based on the provided character
    //     separator.
```

If you add `1` as the second parameter, then you're asking the function to split the string with the separator but return "only one" value in the resulting array. The function then returns an array with only the original string because that is only way it can think to split the array with exactly-one element in the array!

Therefore the above code returns `["https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.5/python-3.9.5-embed-amd64.zip"]` as the value for the variable `zip_url_words`. Change the above code like so:

```
string[] zip_url_words = zip_url.Split('/');
```

When you make this change, then the function returns an array with the split that you expect `['https:','','www.python.org','ftp','python','3.9.5','python-3.9.5-embed-amd64.zip']`

I made the change and the code works for me.

Comment: great answer @sushant, though it doesn't explain why would it not work with 1 added as second argument

Comment: @zooid Thanks for the feedback. I should have been more descriptive. I have made edits.

Comment: FWIW I think there's a bug in this function, as having 1 in there should also return a truncated result, but it doesn't it returns the full string.
`Remarks
If the string has already been split count - 1 times, but the end of the string has not been reached, then the last string in the returned array will contain this instance's remaining trailing substring, untouched.` as it says in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0

Comment: Returning the entire string when you put 1 for count is exactly consistent with your quote from the documentation. Specifically, the string has already been split 0 times (count -1), so it is returning the remaining trailing substring (everything from the last split to the end of the string, aka everything from the beginning of the string to the end) untouched, so it is definitely not a bug, but rather is the documented and intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I changed

```
string[] zip_url_words = zip_url.Split('/', 1);
```

to

```
string[] zip_url_words = zip_url.Split('/', '1');
```

and

```
string[] url_word_array = url.Split('/', 1);
```

to

```
string[] url_word_array = url.Split('/', '1');
```

I downloaded
Could you try one more time?

Comment: This will treat `1` as a separator, which isn't what the OP wants

Comment: Wow, that worked, as surprising as the "split" not working :D I'll accept your answer in 4 mins :D

Comment: @zooid How could you compile?

Comment: well Visual Studio 2019 compiles without any warnings

Comment: @zooid If this does what you want, just do `url.Split('/')`, without the `'1'`.That way you won't accidentally split in the middle of a filename if it happens to contain the character '1'. As it is, the input `https://www.python.org/ftp/python/1.0.0/python-1.0.0-embed-amd64.zip` will result in `.0.0-embed-amd64.zip`, which isn't what you want

Comment: that also works thanks @canton7

Comment: @Beso, when I use standalone netcore (without VS) I get `error CS1001: Identifier expected` when I try to compile.

Comment: @zooid which line of code?

Comment: `void file_download(string url, string save_path)` this one, which is very weird. Even if I change it to System.String it shows the same error
`Program.cs(15,30): error CS1001: Identifier expected`
`Program.cs(15,52): error CS1001: Identifier expected`

Comment: @zooid You should write this function out of Main

Comment: that makes no difference

Comment: did you set:
static void file_download(string url, string save_path)

Comment: OMG, I found the issue, I had no Main function in the file I used with the standalone netcore :), getting the function out of the Main worked :), thanks @Beso